# Modern IE site not giving Mac downloads

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, modern.ie

Anyone else have this experience.  I just went to the Modern IE site to download virtual machines for VMWare for Mac.  I made double and triple sure I was on the Mac tab, but for some reason everything from IE9 up kept giving me the Windows VM, not the Mac.  Is there perhaps some trick I don't know about, or is there another way to get these?   Thanks in advance to anyone who has some insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the name of the file. It will work just fine in your Mac. We are in the process of changing how VMs are built and renamed and we haven't finished these ones yet.

Source: I'm the PM of dev.modern.ie